# Criação de imagems com texto 'imagecreate()'

Tags: php, html, header, image

Isso vai ser bastante dificil de entender, pelo fato de não ter uma explicação bem dinamica. Tentarei ser o mais claro possivel!

Quero criar um gerador de letras identico a esse:

http://image.prntscr.com/image/359de73d9e0845a7bf0dbd7675ce8a8f.png

Este é o site: http://www.pixelacao.zz.mu/

Porém como tudo comigo tem que ser dificil a criação da imagem deu errado.
não sei onde e nem porque o codigo não executa perfeitamente, e nenhum lugar relata erro.

Revisei o código varias vezes e não consigo achar o erro.

Isto é oque acontece quando executo: http://image.prntscr.com/image/cc41fe8a64bd442f8be94d243a07ab5e.png

```
<?php

$date = time();
//header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$date.png");
header('Content-type: image/png');

error_reporting(10);
$text = $_GET['text'];
$folder = $_GET['folder'];
$spacing = $_GET['space'];
if($spacing == ""){
    $spacing = 0;
}
if($text == ""){
    $text = "Habbo";
    $spacing = -2;
}

if($folder == ""){
    $folder = "wabbo4";
}

if($spacing == ""){
    if($folder == "1"){
        $spacing = 1;
    }
    if($folder == "2"){
        $spacing = 1;
    }
    if($folder == "3"){
        $spacing = -1;
    }
}
$folder = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9s]/", "", $folder);
if(!is_dir($folder)){
    $folder = "1";
}

$length = strlen($text);

for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){

    $letter = substr($text, $i, 1);
    if($letter == "+"){
        $imgwidth = $imgwidth+5+$spacing;
    }else{
        if (preg_match("/[a-z]/", $letter)) {
            $letterimg = imagecreatefrompng("".$folder."/".$letter.".png"); 
            $letterimgwidth = ImageSX($letterimg);
            $letterimgheight = ImageSY($letterimg);
            $yoffset = 21-$letterimgheight;
            $imgwidth = $imgwidth+$letterimgwidth+$spacing;
        }elseif (preg_match("/[A-Z]/", $letter)){
            $letter = strtolower($letter);
            $letterimg = imagecreatefrompng("".$folder."/".$letter.".png"); 
            $letterimgwidth = ImageSX($letterimg);
            $letterimgheight = ImageSY($letterimg);
            $yoffset = 21-$letterimgheight;
            $imgwidth = $imgwidth+$letterimgwidth+$spacing;
        }else{
            $imgwidth = $imgwidth+5;
        }
    }
}

$imgwidth = $imgwidth-$spacing+1;

$im = imagecreate($imgwidth, $letterimgheight+1);
$overimageheight = $letterimgheight+1;
$background = imagecolorallocatealpha($im, 0, 255, 0, 0);
imagecolortransparent($im, $background);
$xcoord = 1;
for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){

    $letter = substr($text, $i, 1);
    if($letter == "+"){
        $xcoord = $xcoord+5+$spacing;
    }else{
        if (preg_match("/[a-z]/", $letter)) {
            $letterimg = imagecreatefrompng("".$folder."/".$letter.".png"); 
            $letterimgwidth = ImageSX($letterimg);
            $letterimgheight = ImageSY($letterimg);
            $yoffset = $overimageheight-$letterimgheight;
            if($letter == "g" || $letter == "j" || $letter == "q" || $letter == "p" || $letter == "y"){
            }
            imagecopy($im, $letterimg, $xcoord, $yoffset, 0, 0, $letterimgwidth, $letterimgheight); 
            $xcoord = $xcoord+$letterimgwidth+$spacing;
        }elseif (preg_match("/[A-Z]/", $letter)){
            $letter = strtolower($letter);
            $letterimg = imagecreatefrompng("".$folder."/".$letter.".png"); 
            $letterimgwidth = ImageSX($letterimg);
            $letterimgheight = ImageSY($letterimg);
            $yoffset = $overimageheight-$letterimgheight;
            imagecopy($im, $letterimg, $xcoord, $yoffset, 0, 0, $letterimgwidth, $letterimgheight); 
            $xcoord = $xcoord+$letterimgwidth+$spacing;
        }else{
            $xcoord = $xcoord+5;
        }
    }
}
header("Content-type: image/png");

imagepng($im); 
imagedestroy($im);

?>
```

No caso folder seria a pasta onde esta as letras, explicando melhor, o usuario escreve o testo e a folder seria a fonte onde pegaria a letra a,b,c...
space seria o espaço entre as letras por que algumas fontes precisam de um espaço maior.

segue imagem:

http://image.prntscr.com/image/bb8eab9bd39543729de97c456457b8b6.png

O resultado como falei seria o texto formado pelas letras de determinada fonte, porém ele da erro, NÃO RELATA NENHUM ERRO NO PHP.

Preciso dessa ajuda, nunca fui bom com imagecreate();
Espero que tenha sido claro com meu problema.

Comment: Pode me explicar a intenção dessa `regex` : `[^a-zA-Z0-9s]` ?

Comment: Para pegar apenas letras de A-Z e numeros 0-9 Caso o usuarios coloque outros caracteres como " []!@#$%¨&*()" ele remove a regex está certa?. . Desculpe a demora, estava jantando.  @MagicHat

Comment: Confundi `preg_match`com `preg_replace`..

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade não foi muito claro não, na próxima vez tenta melhorar a descrição com imagens, tentativas de falhas e sucesso, casos detalhados de debug, etc...

Enfim, nessa função você deseja inserir um conteúdo (INPUT) e apenas alterar a fonte deste conteúdo ? Se eu estiver correto, fiz um código rapidinho que está auto explicativo, dê uma analisada e qualquer dúvida pergunte.

```js
function generateText() {
    // Getting the values
    var initialText = document.getElementById("initialText").value;
    var finalText = document.getElementById("finalText");
    var fontSource = document.getElementById("fontSource").value;

    finalText.innerHTML = initialText;
    switch (fontSource) {
        case "arial":
            finalText.style.fontFamily = "arial, sans-serif";
            break;
        case "lucida":
            finalText.style.fontFamily = "lucida, sans-serif";
            break;
        case "verdana":
            finalText.style.fontFamily = "verdana, sans-serif";
            break;
    }
}
```

```html
<input id="initialText" type="text" placeholder="Texto">
<select id="fontSource">
    <option value="arial">Arial</option>
    <option value="lucida">Lucida</option>
    <option value="verdana">Verdana</option>
</select>

<button onclick="generateText()">Alterar fonte</button>
<p id="finalText"></p>
```

Deseja transformar algum conteúdo da sua página em imagem ? Utilize [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/). Resolvendo seu problema ou não, retorne com seu feedback.